# system of congruences has a solution if GCD = 1

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have the following problem.

Let m, n be arbitrary non zero integers.
Show that
 $x ≡ a \pmod m$
 $x ≡ b\pmod n$
has a solution if  $\gcd(m, n)$ divides both $a$ and $b$.

Also interested in the converse.

I've tried messing around with various thing, including bezout's identity, and euler's function, but haven't really made much progress. Have also tried some group theory but I really don't have a solid basis in that.

Comment: Are $M$ and $N$ the same as $m$ and $n$, respectively? If so, you should be consistent in your notation. If not, what purpose do $M$ and $N$ serve in this question?

Comment: @JohnDouma yes, they are the same. Editing issue, fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Set $d=\gcd(m,n)$. Show the congruences imply a solution is divisible by $d$. So set $$x=yd,\quad m=m'd,\quad n=n'd,\quad a=da',\quad b=db'.$$
Note that $m'$ and $n'$ are coprime and the system of congruences 
can be rewritten as
\begin{cases}
y\equiv a'\pmod{m'},\\
y\equiv b'\pmod{n'}.
\end{cases}

The converse is not true. What is true uis that the system of congruences has a solution if and only  if $a\equiv b\mod\gcd(m,n)$ (this condition is of course satisfied with your hypotheses.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Would I be right in thinking that I can use bezout's identity to show that the solution is divisible by d?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary. The mere definition of a congruence and the hypotheses will be enough.

Comment: Thinking over it again, you'll need some form of Bézout's identity to prove the full necessary and sufficient condition I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a partial conclusion of Chinese Remainder Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and the direct side is correct. For the converse notice the following counter example$$x\equiv5\pmod{2}\\x\equiv3\pmod{4}$$which has the answer $x=15$ but $$\gcd(2,4)=2\nmid \quad3,5$$